# Python quiz code improvement, maybe with a popup?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie here so sorry if I accidentally break any rules. Basically I'm a beginner to Python and have made a piece of code for a quiz on TV Show Trivia. I wanted to ask the community here if there are any ways to tidy it up, such as unnecessary repetition etc. Also, I wanted to know if there is a way to make it so that the quiz appears in a pop up window, with a space to type in the answer. Here is the code I have so far:

```
print("Shall we start?")
input("Press Enter to continue...")
score = 0

Que_1 = input("Who's missing - Rachel, Ross, Chandler, Pheobe?: ")
if Que_1 == "Monica" or "monica":
    print("That's right, well done!!")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("I'm sorry, that's the wrong answer :( ")
    score = score - 1

Que_2 = input("What is the first name of the women Leonard from The Big Bang 
Theory ended up marrying?: ")
if Que_2 == "Penny" or "penny":
    print("Congratulations, that was correct!!")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("Incorrect")
    score = score - 1

Que_3 = input("What is the full name of the actor who plays the 10th 
Doctor?: ")
if Que_3 == "David Tennant" or "david tennant":
    print("Oui")
    score = score + 1
else:
    ("Non")
    score = score - 1

Que_4 = input("Which sister died in Charmed?: ")
if Que_4 == "Prue" or "prue":
    print("You know it")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("You don't know it")
    score = score - 1

Que_5 = input("Who is the main character of 13 reasons why(Full Name)?: ")
if Que_5 == "Hannah Baker" or "hannah baker":
    print("Correctumondo")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("Failumundo")
    score = score - 1

Que_6 = input("Complete the name 'Tracy ______': ")
if Que_6 == "Beaker" or "beaker":
    print("Perfect")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("Not perfect")
    score = score - 1

Que_7 = input("Lily, Jas and ______ : ")
if Que_7 == "Martha" or "martha":
    print("On the button")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("Sucks to be you")
    score = score - 1

Que_8 = input("Is Missy from Ackley Bridge straight, lesbian or bisexual?:")
if Que_8 == "Straight" or "straight":
    print("Right on")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("Way off")
    score = score - 1

Que_9 = input("From the 4 o' Clock Club, who is Josh's brother?: ")
if Que_9 == "Nathan" or "nathan":
    print("Unmistaken")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("Mistaken")
    score = score - 1

Que_10 = input("What does Sophie from My Parents Are Aliens have to eat in 
order to shapeshift? : ")
if Que_10 == "Ice cream" or "Ice Cream" or "ice cream":
    print("Amen to that")
    score = score + 1
else:
    print("Ughhhh just no")
    score = score - 1

if score == 10:
    print("10 out of 10. Your a boss at this")

elif 5 <= score < 10:
    print("Your score is", score, "pretty good, try to get 10 next time")

elif 1 <= score < 10:
    print("Your score is", score, "Better luck next time")
```

Comment: You should go ahead and put this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have you even tested this code yet to guarantee that it works as-is? Looking at it, I have doubts. Check those `if` conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (I did not include all the questions):

```
questions = [
    "Who's missing - Rachel, Ross, Chandler, Pheobe?: ",
    "What is the first name of the women Leonard from The Big Bang Theory ended up marrying?: ",
    "What is the full name of the actor who plays the 10th Doctor?: ",
    "Which sister died in Charmed?: "
]

answers = [
    "monica",
    "penny",
    "david tennant",
    "prue"
]

yes_nos = [
    ["That's right, well done!!", "I'm sorry, that's the wrong answer :( "],
    ["Congratulations, that was correct!!", "Incorrect"],
    ["Oui", "Non"],
    ["You know it", "You don't know it"]
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Shall we start?")
    input("Press Enter to continue...")
    score = 0

    for i, q in enumerate(questions):
        ans = input(q + '\n').lower()
        if ans == answers[i]:
            print(yes_nos[i][0])
            score += 1
        else:
            print(yes_nos[i][1])
        print()

    if score == 10:
        print("10 out of 10. Your a boss at this")
    elif 5 <= score < 10:
        print("Your score is", score, "\nPretty good, try to get 10 next time")
    elif 1 <= score < 10:
        print("Your score is", score, "\nBetter luck next time")
```

Answer (score 0):

[Easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net) is great for small dialog boxes:

```
response = easygui.enterbox("What is your favorite ice cream flavor?")
```

Which will pop up a window like [this](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/enterbox.png).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In term of optimization, you can use the method `lower()`

```
if Que_1.lower() ==  "monica":
```

That will remove the first letter as an upper case

You can also use += 1

```
print("That's right, well done!!")
score += 1
```

You will not need to do `score = score + 1`

And on the first `Que_1`, you need to set after the `else` with the score that equals to 0 as it is your first if.

You may need to check dictionaries and if it can help you.

And last, you can use this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40875/dynamic-user-created-menus-with-sub-menus-in-a-command-line-script) to give you some insight about what you can do.